# Deploying a Dynamic Web Project with Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I currently have a working servlet created in Eclipse. When running it from the Tomcat plugin, everything works, and my app shows up at localhost:8080/project_name/. However, when I package the project into a .war file and place it in the /webapps directory of Tomcat and start the server, the servlet cannot be accessed. In Terminal, I can see Tomcat loading my project, and a temporary folder of the unarchived project is also created in /webapps. However, I simply cannot access my servlet.

Note:
I'm using Tomcat 7 and I don't have a web.xml file in my project.

Comment: Your URL should be `localhost:8080/project_name/Servlet_Path`.

Comment: I have a Servlet mapped to "localhost:8080/project_name/" with the annotation WebServlet(""), but that doesn't work. Furthermore, where is the project name stored?

Comment: In tomcat 7, project is stored at webapps directory. You should use IDE integrated tomcat server to see what is happend and run project from IDE.

Answer (score 1):

How are you creating the war file? Check if your war files contain jar files under WEB-INF/lib folder and if the class files are not missing. You can easily verify it under tomcat/webapps/[project name] folder.

Comment: I'm not using any external libraries in my servlet. Furthermore, all of my classes are under WEB-INF/classes.